# What does the '~~' (double tilde) operator do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon this for the first time, what does the ~~n mean in JavaScript?

```
var isSquare = function(n) {
   n = Math.sqrt(n);
   return n == ~~n;
}
```

I know that the code checks if n is a "perfect" square.

Comment: See this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators (bitwise not)